# How to add and remove html element with javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a number of `CheckBox` elements in my html page. What I want is whenever any of these are checked, dynamically add one `input type='checkbox'` to the html page. If unchecked then remove the element which was added. No element should be repeated.

```
<html><head>
            <title>Welcome ! eDetailing :: Admin</title>
           </head>
        <body id="bdload">

    <form name="frm" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="deleteId" id="deleteId" value="3">
    <input type="hidden" name="nextId" id="nextId" value="1-0">
    <input type="hidden" name="prvId" id="prvId" value="4-0">

    <!----------------------------------------------media Information ------------------------------------------------------>
        <div id="faqtable1" class="icongroup2">
            <div class="clBlock">
    <!--*****************************************************************************-->
                <div class="clRow">
                    <div class="clLeft">
                        <span id="docFname" class="col1">
                           <label class="clsvlabel" for="selMediaTitle">Media Title : </label>
                        </span>
                        <span class="col2 clWrite">
                            <label class="labelshow" style="display: none; ">media 2</label>
                             <select name="selMediaTitlen" class="clsvtext clvselectempty" id="selMediaTitle" style="display: inline-block; "> 
                                <option value="">Media Title</option>
                                <option value="42">Energy</option> 
                                  <option value="43" selected="selected">media 2</option> 
                                  <option value="44">media 3</option> 
                                  <option value="45">media 4</option> 
                                  <option value="46">mediapicture</option> 
                                  <option value="47">mediavid</option> 
                                  <option value="48">mediapdf</option> 
                                                          </select>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>

            <div class="clRow">
                       <div class="clRight1">
                            <span id="docLname" class="col1">
                                <label class="clsvlabel" for="txtmrname"></label>
                            </span>
                            <span class="col2 clWrite2">
                                <div class="clcheckboxlist1">
                                   <div class="clckbxheader">
                                       <input type="checkbox" class="clckbxheadlist1 clsvtextempty" id="ckidh1" style="">
                                       <label for="ckidh1" id="chk1">Check All Doctor</label>
                                       <label for="ckidh1" id="unchk1" style="display:none;">UnCheck All Doctors</label>
                                   </div>
                                   sdsd
                                   <div class="clckbxbody1" id="cklist1">
                                    <span class="clckbxrow"> <input type="checkbox" class="txtshow clsvtextempty" checked="checked" id="28" name="checkMr[]" value="28" style=""><label for="ckid1"><em style="background-color:#00FF7F;" class="emdoclist">Core Ai</em>Zaheerdfsfghg  Sdf</label>
                                                               </span><div name="mydiv&gt;&lt;input type=" checkbox'class="txtshow clsvtextempty" id="28" value="28" class="checkmrdone"></div><span class="clckbxrow"> <input type="checkbox" class="txtshow clsvtextempty" id="6" name="checkMr[]" value="6" style=""><label for="ckid1"><em style="background-color:#00FF7F;" class="emdoclist">Core Ai</em>Prizall Anuj Bagrecha</label>
                                                               </span><span class="clckbxrow"> <input type="checkbox" class="txtshow clsvtextempty" id="7" name="checkMr[]" value="7" style=""><label for="ckid1"><em style="background-color:#00FF7F;" class="emdoclist">Core Ai</em>Javedq Rashid Ansari</label>
                                                               </span><span class="clckbxrow"> <input type="checkbox" class="txtshow clsvtextempty" id="2" name="checkMr[]" value="2" style=""><label for="ckid1"><em style="background-color:#00FF7F;" class="emdoclist">Core Ai</em>Vijay Kumar Asthana</label>
                                                               </span><span class="clckbxrow"> <input type="checkbox" class="txtshow clsvtextempty" id="34" name="checkMr[]" value="34" style=""><label for="ckid1"><em style="background-color:#00FF7F;" class="emdoclist">Core Ai</em>Manish  Malviya</label>
                                                               </span><span class="clckbxrow"> <input type="checkbox" class="txtshow clsvtextempty" id="1" name="checkMr[]" value="1" style=""><label for="ckid1"><em style="background-color:#9ACD32;" class="emdoclist">Core Bi</em>Sujoy Kumar Kale</label>
                                                               </span><span class="clckbxrow"> <input type="checkbox" class="txtshow clsvtextempty" id="4" name="checkMr[]" value="4" style=""><label for="ckid1"><em style="background-color:#9ACD32;" class="emdoclist">Core Bi</em>Avkaash K Tare</label>
                                                               </span><span class="clckbxrow"> <input type="checkbox" class="txtshow clsvtextempty" id="5" name="checkMr[]" value="5" style=""><label for="ckid1"><em style="background-color:#800000;" class="emdoclist">Core Ci</em>Viabhav Shishir Parkhe</label>
                                                               </span>                               </div>

                                   </div>
                            </span>            
                        </div>
                    </div>
    <!--*****************************************************************************-->
                    <div class="clRow">
                        <div class="clLeft">
                            <span id="docFname" class="col1">
                               <label class="clsvlabel" for="chk_active">Active :</label>
                            </span>
                            <span class="col2 clWrite">
                            <label class="labelshow" style="display: none; ">
                                YES 
                            </label>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="chk_active" id="chk_active" value="0" style="width: auto; display: inline-block; " class="clsvtext clvselectempty clsvtextempty" checked="checked">
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
           </div>
      </div>

    </form>
    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        $j("#btnadvsearch").bind("click", function() {
                    $j.ajax({ 
                    type:"POST",
                    url:"advanceSearch.php",
                    data: { name : $j("#advMedia").val(),type : $j("#advType").val(),activ : $j("#selActive").val(),},
                    success:function(response){ 
                    $j("#showResult").html(response);
                    }
                }); 
        });

        </script>

    <div class="Zebra_DatePicker"><table class="dp_header"><tbody><tr><td class="dp_previous">«</td><td class="dp_caption">&nbsp;</td><td class="dp_next">»</td></tr></tbody></table><table class="dp_daypicker"></table><table class="dp_monthpicker"></table><table class="dp_yearpicker"></table></div><div class="Zebra_DatePicker"><table class="dp_header"><tbody><tr><td class="dp_previous">«</td><td class="dp_caption">&nbsp;</td><td class="dp_next">»</td></tr></tbody></table><table class="dp_daypicker"></table><table class="dp_monthpicker"></table><table class="dp_yearpicker"></table></div></body><span id="skype_highlighting_settings" display="none" autoextractnumbers="1"></span><object id="skype_plugin_object" location.href="http://localhost/konnect/mediaAssgin/" location.hostname="localhost" style="position: absolute; visibility: hidden; left: -100px; top: -100px; " width="0" height="0" type="application/x-vnd.skype.click2call.chrome.5.7.0"></object></html>
```

Comment: Use the jQuery remove method or the native removeChild

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use jQuery's [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) function to determine when a checkbox is changed. Then, use the [`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) and [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) functions to remove or add elements, respectively.

If you want to just *hide* an element (but not actually remove it from the DOM), use [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/). You can also set an element's class with [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) if you'd rather use your own custom classes to hide elements.

Don't expect people to just write your code for you. jQuery's docs are pretty good and should be enough to help you get started.